# When does equality in Markov's inequality occur?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Markov's inequality states that given any nonnegative random variable and $a>0$ then we have: 
$$P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{E(X)}{a}$$
At which $a$ is equality supposed to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $X\ge 0$, $$ E[X]=\int_{0}^\infty \Pr[X\ge x] dx\ge \int_{0}^a \Pr[X\ge x] dx\ge (a-0)\cdot \Pr[X\ge a]=a\cdot \Pr[X\ge a]$$

So we can see we need $\Pr[X\ge x]$ constant for $0< x< a$ and $\Pr[X\ge x]=0$ for $x>a$ to have the equality.

Comment: You also get equality if $X$ is compactly supported and symmetrically distributed around $0$ with $a>sup_x\{x|p(X\ge x)\neq 0\}$.

Comment: @abdrido: The question states that $X\ge 0$ so it is impossible for it to be symmetrically distributed around zero.

Comment: @SergioParreiras Thanks.

Comment: @ Sergio Parreiras: you are right. i missed that. but you can still have $P[X=0]=1$ and take $a>0$. so you don't always need $a=\infty$ or $P(X=a)=1$.

Comment: @abdrido : Added your point to the answer.

Comment: You can also get equality when $X$ only takes the values $0$ or $a$, each with non-zero probability. Suppose $X$ takes the values $0$ or $a$ with probability $1-p$ and $p$ respectively. Then $E(X)=ap$ and $P(X\geqslant a)=p$, so we have equality in Markov's inequality.

Comment: @JonCC: That's right. I removed the last assertions. I prefer your answer.

Comment: The conditions on $X$ as stated are unclear. It happens these can be greatly simplified.

Comment: @Did: JonCC answer below does that

Comment: I know. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 7):

First assume $a$ is finite, otherwise the result is trivial. Define the random variable $Y_{a}=X-a1_{\{X \geq a\}}$, where $$1_{\{X \geq a\}}=
\begin{cases}
1, \:\text{if}\; X\geqslant a\\
0, \:\text{if}\; X< a
\end{cases}.$$

Observe that $Y_a$ is non-negative. Taking the expectation yields $$E(Y_a)=E(X)-aP(X \geq a).$$

Hence Markov's inequality holds with equality if and only if $E(Y_a)=0$. Since $Y_a$ is non-negative, this is equivalent to $P(Y_{a}=0)=1$. Note that $Y_{a}=0$ if and only if $X=0$ or $X=a$.

Therefore, Markov's inequality holds with equality if and only if $P(X\in\{0,a\})=1$.

Answer (score -2):

You get equality when $X$ is a random variable that takes on value $a$ with probability $1$. For any non-constant non-negative random variable, you will always have $P(X \geq a) < E(X)/a$ because the quantity $a P(X \geq a)$ is less than or equal to a strict partial contribution to the expectation $E(X)$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment .

Comment: This is wrong, take $X$ uniform on $\{0,1\}$ and $a=1$.